# Filter a list of strings by frequency

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings:

```
a = ['book','book','cards','book','foo','foo','computer']
```

I want to return anything in this list that's `x > 2`

Final output:

```
a = ['book','book','book']
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach this. But here's two methods I had in mind:

Approach One:

I've created a dictionary to count the number of times an item appears:

```
a = ['book','book','cards','book','foo','foo','computer'] 

import collections

def update_item_counts(item_counts, itemset):
    for a in itemset:
        item_counts[a] +=1

test = defaultdict(int)
update_item_counts(test, a)
print(test)

Out: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'book': 3, 'cards': 1, 'foo': 2, 'computer': 1})
```

I want to filter out the list with this dictionary but I'm not sure how to do that.

Approach two:
I tried to write a list comprehension but it doesn't seem to work:

```
res = [k for k in a if a.count > 2 in k]
```

Comment: Your second approach should be `res = [k for k in a if a.count(k) > 2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a_list = ['book','book','cards','book','foo','foo','computer'] 
b_list = []

for a in a_list:
    if a_list.count(a) > 2:
        b_list.append(a)

print(b_list)
#  ['book', 'book', 'book']
```

Edit: You mentioned list comprehension. You are on the right track! You can do it with list comprehension like this:

```
a_list = ['book','book','cards','book','foo','foo','computer'] 
c_list = [a for a in a_list if a_list.count(a) > 2]
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

A very barebone answer is that you should replace `a.count` by `a.count(k)` in your second solution.

Although, do not attempt to use `list.count` for this, as this will traverse the list for each item. Instead count occurences first with `collections.Counter`. This has the advantage of traversing the list only once.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat

a = ['book','book','cards','book','foo','foo','computer']
count = Counter(a)

output = [word for item, n in count.items() if n > 2 for word in repeat(item, n)]

print(output) # ['book', 'book', 'book']
```

Note that the list comprehension is equivalent to the loop below.

```
output = []

for item, n in count.items():
    if n > 2:
        output.extend(repeat(item, n))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['book','book','cards','book','foo','foo','computer']
list(filter(lambda s: a.count(s) > 2, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt builds a dictionary with all of the counts. You need to take this a step further to get the items that you want:

```
res = [k for k in test if test[k] > 2]
```

Now that you have built this by hand, you should check out the builtin `Counter` class that does all of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print there are better answers already, if you want to remove you can try this.

```
a = ['book','book','cards','book','foo','foo','computer'] 
countdict = {}

for word in a:
  if word not in countdict:
    countdict[word] = 1
  else:
    countdict[word] += 1

for x, y in countdict.items():
  if (2 >= y):
    for i in range(y):
      a.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
def my_filter(my_list, my_freq):
'''Filter a list of strings by frequency'''

# use set() to unique my_list, then turn set back to list
unique_list = list(set(my_list))

# count frequency in unique_list
frequencies = []
for value in unique_list:
    frequencies.append(my_list.count(value))

# filter frequency
return_list = []

for i, frequency in enumerate(frequencies):
    if frequency > my_freq:
        for _ in range(frequency):
            return_list.append(unique_list[i])

return return_list



a = ['book','book','cards','book','foo','foo','computer']
my_filter(a, 2)
```

['book', 'book', 'book']